# Can I use msbuild 4.0 to target dotnet 3.5?

Tags: msbuild, .net-framework-version

In my solution I have project references to (e.g.) System.ServiceModel.dll where "use specific version" is set to false. 
Everything builds fine with msbuild 3.5.

I'd like to use msbuild 4.0 in order to use [property functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx). I tried passing in properties "TargetFrameworkVersion=3.5;ToolsVersion=3.5". However, I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.configuration.dll' or one of its dependencies.

This doesn't happen if I use msbuild 3.5.

Can I make this work without specifying versions in the project files? (In future we may want to upgrade the application to dotnet 4)

Edit: I tried using msbuild 3.5 in the "outer" call, and invoking msbuild (using an`<msbuild>`task) 4.0 for those targets requiring the new functionality. No luck with this either - the inner invocation gives the following error message:

> error MSB4062: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0 or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, and that the assembly and all its dependencies are available.

Comment: The answer to the headline question is "Yes".  I suspect the answer to your second question (targeting the assembly references without project changes) may be "No".  
Have you targeted the specific project to .NET 3.5? I mean, not its dependencies but the target framework for the project itself. You could modify those a lot more easily in the future.

Comment: The solution is VS2008. All the projects target either 3.5 or 2.0.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually calling the `MSBuild.exe` version 4.0 executable? It is installed in `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\` (for 32bit). Or make sure you use the VS2010 command prompt (not the VS2008 command prompt).

Answer (score 5):

The parameter to pass to msbuild is:

```
/p:TargetFrameworkVersion="v3.5"
```

This is available in MSBuild version 3.5 and greater (3.5, 4.0, 2012, 2013, etc). It changes the property within the msbuild script for that build.

Extra note is that you could even specify all target versions installed on the machine for each of the MSBuild versions. Typically you can't do it in Visual Studio (e.g. use 4.5.1 in 2010), however MSBuild 4.0 (vs2010) will take it as a property value and use it.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
/p:TargetFramework=v3.5
```

The target framework version can either be v2.0, v3.0 or v3.5. If you are reference assemblies that are not in a given target framework version, then you will get errors/warnings at build time.

References:

- [Multi targeting - How does it work?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/11/15/multi-targeting-how-does-it-work.aspx)
- [MSDN - Common MSBuild Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx)